# dateFromString STILL returns nul

Tags: xcode, ios7, null, nsdateformatter

I am still kinda new to Objective C.  I've searched and searched, applied everything that I've found and I STILL get nul returns.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [dateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"08/24/2014"];
```

And all I get is nul.  PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test string doesn't seem to match your format; if the format is "dd/MM/yyyy" then the string indicates a date on the 8th day of the 24th month of 2014.

Comment: OMG!! I guess it helps to have another pair of eyes. LOL The hours of frustration. Thank You!